# 0D0D turns into 0D on binascii.hexlify(file.read())

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to read a file's hex code using file.read() & binascii.hexlify(), and in place of 0D 0D in the original file python reads/prints only one 0D.

ex:

original file: 6D 6F 64 65 2E **0D 0D** 0A 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

python: `print(binascii.hexlify(f.read(16)))` output: 6d6f64652e**0d**0a24000000000000001c

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: `original file` has the text characters you showed or is the file binary? How did you open the file?  If possible, you really should switch to Python 3.8+.

Comment: @wwii What I showed for the "original file" is the hex preview of an exe file. I also cant switch to a different version of python as this is for a class assignment and we work with python 2.7

Comment: It looks like you opened the file in text mode, which caused the endlines to be modified (0D and 0A are endline characters).

Comment: @yaya1711, @zvone is right. If you are on Windows, you should open non-text files in binary mode, i.e., `file = open(path, 'rb')`.